# How do I distribute an in-house app in iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, distribution, apple-business-manager

I am researching to find the different ways an in-house app can be distributed with Apple. Just to be clear what we need is to distribute a private app that can only be used by the members of our organization.

I know the App Store rejects this kind of apps, so my question is, what is the official way that Apple gives us to do this?

I've been searching and I've found the [Apple business manager](https://support.apple.com/es-es/guide/apple-business-manager/apdd344cdd9d/web), but reading the documentation I don't know if it is what I'm looking for. Has somebody used it before? How does it work? Does it need an external MDM to work or apple gives us one?

Note: I know this has been asked before, I've gone through all the questions and I've posted this one because the others are outdated.

Comment: The best approach is probably to use a B2B app. This is used via Apple Business Manager, and yes, it is best to use an MDM.  You should really be managing your devices via an MDM anyway, and if they are company owned devices you should use device enrolment to force them to use the MDM

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/304/

Comment: @Paulw11 does Apple provide a MDM solution or do I have to use an external one (like jamf or manageengine)?

Comment: You have to use an external solution. I think there is a limited MDM offering in macOS server, but I suggest you look at JAMF. Cisco Meraki had a free tier that let you manage up to 100 devices, not sure if this is still available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some more deeper research I have found that the Custom Apps are the best solution.

To clarify for those as confused as me, there are two methods: in House and Custom Apps.

- In House is described by Apple as "no longer the standard" but still working. It apparently needs an MDM to work, also an Apple Enterprise developer Program membership. The apps expire every year so you have to keep an eye on it.
- Custom App (the new way of doing it). It doesn't need an MDM to work (but can be used with it), the other option is to provide redemption codes that an user can use to download the app in the App Store (or with a direct link also provided by Apple). You won't need an Apple Enterprise developer Program membership but a normal Apple Developer Program membership (an the organization will have to be registered in the Apple Business Manager).

[Here](https://www.coletiv.com/blog/distribute-custom-b2b-ios-app/) you have a step by step guide to do the complete process.